# How to combine duplicate rows in pandas?

Tags: pandas, merge, duplicates, missing-data

How to combine duplicate rows in pandas, filling in missing values?

In the example below, some rows have missing values in the `c1` column, but the `c2` column has duplicates that can be used as an index to look up and fill in those missing values.

the input data looks like this:

```
    c1  c2
id      
0   10.0    a
1   NaN     b
2   30.0    c
3   10.0    a
4   20.0    b
5   NaN     c
```

desired output:

```
    c1  c2
0   10  a
1   20  b
2   30  c
```

But how to do this?

Here is the code to generate the example data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'c1': [10, float('nan'), 30, 10, 20, float('nan')]
    'c2': [100, 200, 300, 100, 200, 300],
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['c1','c2']).drop_duplicates(['c2'])
print (df)
     c1   c2
0  10.0  100
4  20.0  200
2  30.0  300
```

Or first remove rows with `NaN`s by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['c1']).drop_duplicates(['c2'])
print (df)
     c1   c2
0  10.0  100
2  30.0  300
4  20.0  200
```

---

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['c1']).drop_duplicates(['c1','c2'])
print (df)
     c1   c2
0  10.0  100
2  30.0  300
4  20.0  200
```