# How to combine duplicate rows in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame similar to the one listed below. For some reason, each team is listed twice, one listing corresponding to each column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'Team': ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3'], 'Points for': [5, 10, 15, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 'Points against' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan, 3, 6, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)




Team    Points for  Points against
0   1        5            Nan
1   2       10            Nan
2   3       15            Nan
3   1       Nan            3
4   2       Nan            6
5   3       Nan            9
```

How can I just combine rows of duplicate team names so that there are no missing values? This is what I would like:

```
 Team   Points for  Points against
0   1        5             3
1   2       10             6
2   3       15             9
```

I have been trying to figure it out with pandas, but can't seem to get it. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine duplicate rows in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302813/how-to-combine-duplicate-rows-in-pandas)

Comment: Just remove all the Nans from your input and remove the duplicate index values:
    `d = {'Team': ['1', '2', '3'], 'Points for': [5, 10, 15], 'Points against' : [3, 6, 9]}`.  Or are you saying the data comes to you in this dirty format and you want help cleaning it?  Ideally you'd fix whatever code produces this dirty data.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the way the data is for some odd reason.

Answer (score 1):

I made changes to your code, replacing string 'Nan' with numpy's nan.

One solution is to [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the data, [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the null entries, and [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) back to wide from long:

```
df = (df
      .melt('Team')
      .dropna()
      .pivot('Team','variable','value')
      .reset_index()
      .rename_axis(None,axis='columns')
      .astype(int)
     )

df


  Team  Points against  Points for
0   1      3              5
1   2      6              10
2   3      9              15
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `groupby`. :

```
df = df.replace("Nan", np.nan)
new_df = df.groupby("Team").first()
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
      Points for  Points against
Team                            
1            5.0             3.0
2           10.0             6.0
3           15.0             9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `groupby` the unique identifiers. If there is also a game ID or date or something like that, you might need to group on that as well.

```
df.groupby('Team').agg({'Points for': 'max', 'Points against': 'max'})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values = ['Points for','Points against'],index=['Team'], aggfunc=np.sum)[['Points for','Points against']]
```

## Output

```
      Points for  Points against
Team                            
1            5.0             3.0
2           10.0             6.0
3           15.0             9.0
```